# Javascript promise chaining with promise.all not working?

Tags: javascript, promise

I have the following code. When i run it i get this error " Cannot read property 'then' of undefined" at the first line in my code when calling getQueryToShift. It seems like getQueryToShift is not working like I intended. What is the correct way to use Promise.all so that the original promise I am declaring on the first line waits for all the promises in the promises array declared inside the getQueryToShift function to resolve before executing what is inside the then block ?

```js
promise = getQueryToShift(hourDiff, options, map, baseBuildStart, oldFrom).then(values => { // error is here
  // wait for promise before handling data in map passed as parameter
});


function getQueryToShift(hourDiff, options, map, baseBuildStart, oldFrom) {

  let promises = [];
  datasourceSrv.get(options.targets[0].datasource).then(ds => {
    for (let i = 0; i < daysDiff - 1; i++) {
      options.range.from._d = dateToMoment(oldFrom, false).add(i, 'h').toDate();
      options.range.to._d = dateToMoment(options.range.from._d, false).add(1, 'h').toDate();
      ds.query(options).then(result => {
        promises.push(createQueryPromise(map, baseBuildStart, result.data));
      });
    }
    return Promise.all(promises);
  });
}

function createQueryPromise(map, baseBuildStart, data) {

  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    data.forEach(datum => {
      //parsing data and adding it to map passed in as parameter
    })
    resolve();
  });
}
```

Comment: Have `getQueryToShift` return something.  `return datasourceSrv.get(...);`

Comment: @zero298 It does fix the error by doing so thanks. However the code inside `getQueryToShift(hourDiff, options, map, baseBuildStart, oldFrom).then(values => {` is executed before the code inside the newly created promises in  `createQueryPromise`. Am I resolving the promises at the wrong time when calling `resolve()` ?

Comment: Is `createQueryPromise` actually asynchronous?  What does it do?  Does it reach out to any APIs?

Comment: Can't really show a full solution without seeing the actual code for `createQueryPromise()`.  If there is an async operation in their, then we need to see it.  If not, then there is no need for a promise at all.  In either case, the `for` loop in `getQueryToShift()` has to get rewritten based on how `createQueryPromise()` actually works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is incomplete because `createQueryPromise()` function makes no sense by itself.  It does not show an asynchronous operation at all, thus without one there is no need for a promise.  And, if there is an asynchronous operation inside your `.forEach()` look, then you will need to coordinate that async operation, but you don't show the code for that so we can't help you fix that and we need to understand what that function is actually doing before we can help with a full and correct implementation of `getQueryToShift()`.

On top of that, here are a couple other things that need fixing:

You aren't returning your promise from `getQueryToShift()`.  Change this:

```
datasourceSrv.get(options.targets[0].datasource).then(ds => {
```

to this:

```
return datasourceSrv.get(options.targets[0].datasource).then(ds => {
```

---

And, you are ignoring the promise returned by:

```
ds.query(options).then(...)
```

Thus, your code wouldn't wait for that operation to finish.  This is probably the promise that you need to collect in the array and use `Promise.all()` with, not the one you are doing it with.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does the `Promise.all` on an empty array - you need to `return` the promise:

```
function* getDays(daysDiff, oldFrom) {
  for (let i = 0; i < daysDiff - 1; i++) {
    var options = {};
    options.range.from._d = dateToMoment(oldFrom, false).add(i, 'h').toDate();
    options.range.to._d = dateToMoment(options.range.from._d, false).add(1, 'h').toDate();
    yield options;
  }
}
function getQueryToShift(hourDiff, options, map, baseBuildStart, oldFrom) {
  // return here
  return datasourceSrv.get(options.targets[0].datasource).then(ds => {
    return Promise.all(
      Array.from(getDays(daysDiff, oldFrom), option => db.query(option))
    );
  });
}
```

Although I warmly recommend using an async function instead:

```
async function getQueryToShift(hourDiff, options, map, baseBuildStart, oldFrom) {
  const ds = await datasourceSrv.get(options.targets[0].datasource);
  await Promise.all(Array.from(getDays(daysDiff, oldFrom), db.query));
}
```